# why for in loop showing undefined value

Tags: javascript, undefined, console.log, for-in-loop

I am having trouble understanding how this for-in loop showing Undefined values at the end in JavaScript, but in loop the length of first is 3. So, why so many undefined values.

```
<div class="tab-menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="first">first item</li>
        <li id="second">second item</li>
        <li id="third">third item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the loop -

```
var first = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-menu ul li");
var f;
for (var i in first) {
    f = first[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(f);
}
```

It'll give this in console -

```
"first item"
"second item"
"third item"
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: You have to understand how does `for...in` loop works. Use `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `forEach`.

```
var first = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-menu ul li")

first.forEach(function(e) {
  var f = e.innerHTML
  console.log(f)
})
```

Comment: so,which one is better to use and also fast - simple for or forEach?